# How ot use unknown parameters in a swagger request

Tags: swagger

I'm posting some form data in the request body. something like:

```
{
  formField1Name: formField1Value,
  formField2Name: formField2Value,
  ...
}
```

the form field names are not known! and the values can be of the type `string|string[]`. how can i describe that with swagger? i was not able to use `additionalProperties` properly:

```
parameters: 
  additionalProperties:
    in: "body"
    description: "list of form field results"
    required: true
    type: "string"
```

Comment: What have you tried and how did it not work for you?

Comment: i tried to replace the `name: "keyName"` with the `additionalProperties` as an object. and any thing else staying the same:
```parameters:
        additionalProperties:
          in: "body"
          description: "list of form field results"
          required: true
          type: "string"```
but the error says parameters should be an array

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48154175/edit) and include your YAML/JSON code.